# CouchDB View Returns empty rows with Complex Key for Date array comparison

Tags: couchdb, key

I've got a view called "report_data_by_date" which essentially is this:

```
function(doc)
{
  if (doc.report_completed_timestamp)
  {
    emit(doc.report_completed_timestamp, doc);
  }
}
```

which emits something like this:

```
{
        "id": "eade1035fb3dc87baba8bdf64b043c2c",
        "key": [
            2011,
            11,
            9,
            14,
            1,
            26,
            305
        ],
        "value": { /*the doc*/}
}
```

And when I query the view, like this:

```
http://.../_design/ReportMetaData/_view/report_data_by_date
```

I get back the expected results.

However, when I try to query with a key (to match only certain dates), like this (but properly URL encoded):

```
http://.../_design/ReportMetaData/_view/report_data_by_date?key=[2011,{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

I get back something like this:

```
{"total_rows":16,"offset":16,"rows":[]}
```

Where rows is an empty array. I expect to get back the rows which have a year of 2011.

I feel like I'm missing something very trivial, but despite my searching I can't find an answer.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

The reason it is not returning is that you probably do not have an *exact* key of: [2011,{},{},{},{},{},{}] in your data. The key parameter to your view will only return exact matches.

If you want all the keys in 2011 you might want to use a *startkey* and and *endkey* . I have not tested your exact query, but it will probably look something like this:

report_data_by_date?startkey=[2011]&endkey=[2011,{},{},{},{},{},{}]

Comment: Thanks Ryan, for some reason I was under the impression I could use {} as wildcards in just the key query.  Utilizing the startkey and endkey as your example indicates solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think what will help you is the use of the query parameters **startkey** and **endkey**.

I populated a test database with the following two documents,

```
{"_id":"7bb98a75-99aa-481c-9de4-68b682f63068","_rev":"1-db9e34f664de295c76de4c8049b1de50","report_completed_timestamp":[2011,11,9,14,1,26,305]},
{"_id":"f4453fd3-dc3a-47b4-91a9-b28cc092513c","_rev":"1-4c9e78f384ef64700262c6ec148e8fff","report_completed_timestamp":[2012,1,1,0,0,0]}
```

If I retrieve your view using the **key** parameter in your example, I'll get back no results because there is no document with a `report_completed_timestamp` field with that value. To get the documents for 2011, use the following:

```
http://.../ReportMetaData/_design/test/_view/report_data_by_date?startkey=[2011]&endkey=[2011,12,31,11,59,999]
```

This yielded the result you wanted:

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"7bb98a75-99aa-481c-9de4-68b682f63068","key":[2011,11,9,14,1,26,305],"value":{"_id":"7bb98a75-99aa-481c-9de4-68b682f63068","_rev":"1-db9e34f664de295c76de4c8049b1de50","report_completed_timestamp":[2011,11,9,14,1,26,305]}}
```

]}

Check out the Apache wiki for more information: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options

Comment: Thanks for the help. I suppose my confusion was at the (apparent) inability to utilize what I thought to be wildcards in the key based query.  I didn't see anything in the Querying Options wiki which elucidated this for me; was there something specific in the docs I should be reading?

Comment: If you have an SQL background, I'd read the O'Reilly book chapter 21 on CouchDB for SQL Jockeys, http://guide.couchdb.org/. In general it's hard to say if there exists a wildcard option for a given task.